# Retrofit Call.enqueue() send requests in the order that were created?

Tags: android, retrofit2

Imagine this scenario:

I start a **requestA** using the Call.enqueue() method, then, before **requestA** be finished, I start **requestB** at the same endpoint of **requestA**. While I'm using Call.enqueue() method, **requestB** will be executed after **requestA**? Or enqueue() method is just used to do requests asynchronously?

I search that information at docs and here on StackOverflow but all the information is superficial about this specific method.

Here is my code - this same code is used for both requests:

```
foolRequest.enqueue(new Callback<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Response> call,
                            @NonNull retrofit2.Response<Response> response) {
                        //do something
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Response> call, 
                            @NonNull Throwable t) {
                       //do something
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think so,
Otherwise, if you implement your own connection client.
By the source code from OkHttpClient, there is a dispatcher class, save all the enqueue API, and it uses queue to save the relative task

```
synchronized void enqueue(AsyncCall call) {
    if (runningAsyncCalls.size() < maxRequests && runningCallsForHost(call) < maxRequestsPerHost) {
      runningAsyncCalls.add(call);
      executorService().execute(call);
    } else {
      readyAsyncCalls.add(call);
    }
}
```